# Memory Leak With Custom Object Detection Model Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am biggner in tensorflow. I used transfer learning machanism and create custom object detection model using "ssd_resnet101_v1_fpn_keras" pre-trained model.

I follow the below documentation for custom traning:

```
https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html
```

I observed one issue while I used it for detection it takes lot of RAM and not releasing it.

I am sharing you the code snippet where it took lot of RAM and not releasing it.

```
detect_fn = tf.saved_model.load(visa_icon_model)

visa_icon_detections = detect_fn(input_tensor
```

**Memory profiler info:**

```
301   1675.0 MiB    191.8 MiB           1           visa_icon_detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
```

As you can see, it's take 191.8 Mb RAM. It's not releasing it after competion the process.

I used gc.collect() and tf.keras.backend.clear_session() for releasing the memory.

Both is not working for me.

Please anyone can help me how can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was following:

```
# first define detect_fn and decorate with tf.function
detect_fn = tf.function(tf.saved_model.load(visa_icon_model))

# when predicting 
visa_icon_detections = detect_fn.signatures['serving_default'](input_tensor)
```

I did a stress test with about 100 requests (I have a running model inside docker container) and it went for about 3 GB maximum after allocation and it uses about 1.9-2.5 GB stable.